# ¿Cómo listar un top de usuarios con más acciones?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

tengo un problemita con sql.
El tema es que tengo dos tablas relacionadas, una es tb_eventos y la otra tb_usuarios
necesito:

1. listar un top usuarios con más eventos registrados
2. los eventos deben ser tomados en cuenta desde la fecha '2021-10-10' en adelante.

alguien tiene idea de como hacer una consulta como esta?
tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
    select tb_users.name, 
           tb_users.tipo, 
           tb_eventos.titulo, 
           tb_eventos.fecha_evento  
      from tb_eventos 
inner join tb_users 
        on tb_eventos.id_usuario = tb_users.id 
     where fecha_evento >= '2021-10-10' 
       and tipo = 2 
  ORDER BY fecha_evento
```

Comment: Si necesitas los usuarios con más eventos, quiere decir que debes **agrupar** los usuarios y hacer un **conteo de eventos** relacionados con el usuario. Esto se hace con [GROUP BY](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) y [COUNT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html)

Comment: Cual es el top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando GROUP BY sobre el usuario y contando con COUNT el número de apariciones, posteriormente ordenando de forma descendiente por las apariciones y limitando el resultado con LIMIT 10, conseguirías el TOP 10.

```
SELECT 
    tb_users.name, 
    COUNT(*) AS num
FROM 
    tb_eventos join tb_users 
    ON tb_eventos.id_usuario = tb_users.id 
WHERE
    fecha_evento >= '2021-10-10' 
    AND tipo = 2 
GROUP BY tb_users.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10
```